# How to select external microphone

Tags: ios, ipad, swift3, core-audio, audio-recording

I've successfully written a simple recording app for iOS that uses AVAudioRecorder.  So far it works with either the internal microphone or an external microphone if it's plugged in to the headphone jack.  How do I select an audio source that is connected through the USB "lightning port"?  Do I have to dive into Core Audio?

Specifically I'm trying to connect an Apogee Electronics ONE USB audio interface.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using AVAudioSession, get the availableInputs.  The return value is an array of AVAudioSessionPortDescriptions.  Iterate through the array checking the portType property to match your preferred port type, then set the preferredInput using the port description.

## Swift:

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
if let desc = audioSession.availableInputs?.first(where: { (desc) -> Bool in
    return desc.portType == AVAudioSessionPortUSBAudio
}){
    do{
        try audioSession.setPreferredInput(desc)
    } catch let error{
        print(error)
    }
}
```

## Objective-C:

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSString *preferredPortType = AVAudioSessionPortUSBAudio;
for (AVAudioSessionPortDescription *desc in audioSession.availableInputs) {
    if ([desc.portType isEqualToString: preferredPortType]) {
        [audioSession setPreferredInput:desc error:nil];            
    }
}
```

Comment: Sweet!  I'll save Core Audio for another sleepless night.  I'm still waiting on hardware to test it but this was what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to import AVFoundation for that. Using shared instance of AVAudioSession you can identify current route that is AVAudioSessionPortDescription will help you to identify port type.I believe  you can not select particular mic but you can identify and check currentRoute of session

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
AVAudioSessionPortDescription *input = [[session.currentRoute.inputs count] ? session.currentRoute.inputs:nil objectAtIndex:0];

if ([input.portType isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortLineIn]) {
    NSLog(@"Audio Route: Input Port: LineIn");
}
else if ([input.portType isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInMic]) {
    NSLog(@"Audio Route: Input Port: BuiltInMic");
}
else if ([input.portType isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortHeadsetMic]) {
    NSLog(@"Audio Route: Input Port: HeadsetMic");
}
else if ([input.portType isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothHFP]) {
    NSLog(@"Audio Route: Input Port: BluetoothHFP");
}
else if ([input.portType isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortUSBAudio]) {
    NSLog(@"Audio Route: Input Port: USBAudio");
}
else if ([input.portType isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionPortCarAudio]) {
    NSLog(@"Audio Route: Input Port: CarAudio");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Audio Input Port: Unknown: %@",input.portType);
}
```

Comment: the question is tagged as Swift 3