# Is it possible to use external microphone with Kotlin on IOs?

Tags: ios, kotlin, external, microphone

#### Recording external microphone

I've found out it is possible in **Swift on iOS** to use external microphone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44194923/how-to-select-external-microphone)

Is it possible to use and record external microphone in **Kotlin on iOS** too?

#### Little background:

1. I know a bit Kotlin, do not know Swift at all
2. I want to write app for iOS which among other things (taking pictures, synchronizing files, etc.) will record signal from external microphone.

Maybe you do not recommend using Kotlin at all?

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. Did you manage to do this? I keep getting NullPointerException when initializing `AVAudioRecorder` but I can't understand why

Comment: @AmirMV I am sorry, I wrote this question for a colleague who was junior programmer and this was his task. I was not actively developing this feature and do not remember the outcome of this issue

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely possible because if there is not a library for this yet, you can write one. I have not found code for this specific use yet, but if you are willing to get the swift code and create the bridge to your kotlin code you can. There is not much involved in communicating between the two languages.

Kotlin Native / Mobile Multi Platform (MMP) have made interop functionality a relatively straightforward task to complete.

Start looking at the docs and see what you can accomplish. It is still a young part of the kotlin echo system but very well designed and already very capable.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/getting-started.html